# How can I get a size of an embedded array in mongodb?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, mongodb

I know that I have to use aggregate, but Its confusing for me when I have embedded array, please help me to figure this thing out.
I need to get the size of "patients" array, which is in "doctor" object.

Here is my object :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to description as mentioned into above question patients field is an array belonging to doctor object into BSON document.

Mongodb facilitates calculating size of an array using $size operator into $project stage of aggregation pipeline.

As a solution to above question please try executing following aggregate query into MongoDB shell.

```
db.collection.aggregate(

// Pipeline
[

    // Stage 1
    {
        $project: {
            patient_count: {
                $size: '$doctor.patients'
            }
        }
    }

]

);
```